# java.lang.verifyerror expecting a stackmap frame at branch target in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, java-7

I compile my web app(using ant task) on JDK 7 and deploy it on tomcat 6, but get this error:

```
java.lang.verifyerror expecting a stackmap frame at branch
```

Does anyone else recognize this error?

Comment: Have you googled it yet? Or checked "related questions" offered to you while you were typing your question? The web is saturated with answers to your problem.

Comment: Trid all the option suggested in that link , doesnt help.

Comment: Then please make it clear in your question *what you have tried*, and *how it failed to help you*.

Comment: FWIW, there isn't much chance that this: `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` in Tomcat startup options wouldn't work.